# IIS web.config condition

Tags: iis, web-config

I have an Windows server with the following `web.config` setting.
The issue is the line: `<remove fileExtension=".json" />`

How can I rewrite this to allow `.json` files in the `videos` directory?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
                <add value="index.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{R:1}" pattern="^(index\.php|videos)" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="123456789" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".json" /><!-- NEED CONDITION -->
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Add a `<location>` tag for `video` in this `web.config` file and add `.json` back, or simply drop a dedicate `web.config` in the video folder to do the same.

Comment: adding a dedicated `web.config` in the video  folder worked, If you would like to make this an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from the comment.

IIS configuration allows multiple ways to set a setting for your case. More details can be found in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/the-configuration-system-in-iis-7).

You can add a `<location>` tag for `video` in this `web.config` file and add `.json` back.

Alternatively you can simply drop a dedicate `web.config` in the video folder to do the same.